# Copy an element from array and pasting it in the end?

Tags: c

**Error:** I am not getting the desired output

**This is my program flow:**

1. Get the number of elements.
2. Get all elements.
3. Get the position of the element to be replicated.
4. Add the replicated element at the end of the set.
5. Display the set.

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int arr[20],position,i,n,value;
    printf("Enter number of elements in the set\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements in the set\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    printf("Enter the position of element to be replicated\n");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    for(i=n-1;i>=position-1;i--)
        arr[i+1]=arr[i];
    arr[position-1]=value;

    printf("Set after replication is\n");
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign the value of `position`?

Comment: You'll have a problem if n > 20.

Comment: The logic is somewhat wrong and you never assign a value to `position`, therefore it's content is indeterminate and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: And it would also be cleaner to increment the value of `n` (which is the number of elements) because after the duplication there is one more element in the set. Then you could have the same condition `i<n` in both `for` loops. And please indent your code correctly.

Comment: `position` is uninitialised. But suppose it is `0`, then `i>=position-1` will cause further undefined behaviour by breaking the array index limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't understand bad, you want to put the element to be replicated at the end of the array, leaving the other in the same place. The code in this case can be this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int arr[20],position,i,n,value;
    printf("Enter number of elements in the set\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements in the set\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    printf("Enter the position of element to be replicated from 1 to n\n");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    arr[n]=arr[value-1];

    printf("Set after replication is\n");
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)    
       printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: what if `n` > 20? And what about `value` <= 0 or `value` > `n`?